# Adding a space between the 3rd and 4th character of a Canadian postal code

Tags: regex

I currently have to add a space between the 3rd and 4th character Canadian postal codes in an excel file (I want it to go from M1A5Z9  to M1A 5Z9)

I thought about using Split() but I don't think it works for this case. I also tried looking into Regex, but I am not quite sure how to go about using that.

Regex.replace(merp, "(\p{Lu})", " $1").trimstart

I saw the above code on a different post so I figured I could do something similar with mine. Is there a way I can insert a space between the "A" and the "5"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to go the Regex way, you may use this pattern:

```
(?<=^.{3})
```

... and replace for a space.

See example [here](https://regex101.com/r/vAg0vc/1).

Answer (score 1):

There sure is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8. Assuming your string variable is named s, here's the usage: `s.Insert(3, " ")`